# DiffUtil.ItemCallback using reference comparator to check if items are the same

Tags: android, kotlin, android-adapter

Is it a good idea to check if items are same using a reference comparator `===` in the `areItemsTheSame` method ?

For example :

```
class PhotoDiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Photo>() {
            override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Photo, newItem: Photo) = oldItem === newItem
            override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Photo, newItem: Photo) = oldItem == newItem
        }
```

Comment: It's not a good idea. :)

Comment: How these methods should be implemented

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`areItemsTheSame` should only compare something like item ID so diff can proceed to run `areContentsTheSame` and see if there are any changes between old and new object representing the same item.

Referential equality in `areItemsTheSame` implies items are immutable and their content never changes (`areContentsTheSame` will always return `true`) and even if you create new `Photo` for same id/url it will be considered a different item which is wrong.

There's also huge issue that by doing so you're essentially forced to maintain one list of hard references to whatever items you have and keep copying/modifying it between updates.